# protecting against CSRF in asp.net web application when using ajax

Tags: asp.net, csrf

I have an asp web application I wanted to update to prevent cross site request forgery attacks.

I have used the Microsoft auto-generated code from VS 2012, and added it to the master page as described [here](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-csrf). It is working well, but one page posts JSON via an AJAX request to a webmethod

I would like to check this ajax request as well.

The forseeable problems are:

```
var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
   {
        //Set the HttpOnly property to prevent the cookie from
        //being accessed by client side script
                HttpOnly = true,
```

this can obviously be changed, but this would then seem to increase site vulnerability. Is this a significant issue?

I can send the value of the viewstate hidden input with the ajax request, but this will then need to be decoded back into key value pairs to do the equivalent of:

```
(string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
```

Is there an easy way to use existing asp.net methods to do this?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If I follow you, you need to look at the  System.Web.UI.LosFormatter class, which can be used to deserialize from viewstate

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have discovered. I ended up using the LosFormatter, as described by geedubb, by adding the following code to the MasterPage, and assigning the value to a hidden input which is posted back with the ajax request. I did not realise when I posted the question that HttpCookie.HttpOnly property still posts back the cookie on an ajax request, and so can be left set to false.

```
internal string GetToken()
{
    // call the static method to guarantee LosFormatter remains threadsafe
    return GetToken(_antiXsrfTokenValue); 
}
private static string GetCurrentUserName()
{
    var currentUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
    return (currentUser == null) ? string.Empty : currentUser.Name;
}
private static string GetToken(string token)
{
    var los = new System.Web.UI.LosFormatter(true, token);
    var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    var data = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    data.Add("TokenValue",token);
    data.Add("UserNameKey", GetCurrentUserName());
    los.Serialize(writer, data);
    return writer.ToString();
}
internal static void Validate(string token)
{
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    var requestCookie = request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
    var antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;
    var los = new System.Web.UI.LosFormatter(true, antiXsrfTokenValue);
    var xsrfData = (Dictionary<string,string>)los.Deserialize(token);
    if (xsrfData["TokenValue"] != antiXsrfTokenValue || xsrfData["UserNameKey"] != GetCurrentUserName())
    {
        throw new System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.");
    }
}
```

Initially, I had tried sending the value of the _VIEWSTATE hidden input, using the same code

```
       var los = new System.Web.UI.LosFormatter(true, antiXsrfTokenValue);
       var ajaxViewState = los.Deserialize(token)
```

but this threw an error stating the supplied key could not deserialze the string. obviously setting

```
       Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
```

has a more complex key than the supplied key alone. I would be interested if anyone knew how to deserialize a viewstate string with a userKey.

The only problem with the method I have provided is the size of the string posted back - 1976 characters long for a GUID + 6 character username!!!!

If approaching this problem again, I would reference the System.Web.WebPages.dll (used in an mvc project), and use the same methods which create the Html.AntiForgeryToken in MVC

```
namespace System.Web.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides access to the anti-forgery system, which provides protection against
    /// Cross-site Request Forgery (XSRF, also called CSRF) attacks.
    /// </summary>
    public static class AntiForgery
    {
        public static void GetTokens(string oldCookieToken, out string newCookieToken, out string formToken)
        public static void Validate()
```